# Adding new keywords delimeters

Tags: org-mode, minor-mode, tags, keywords

I am new to the Emacs (Doom Emacs to be precise) scene, and recently I came up with a minor mode that could come in handy for me so I decided to implement it.

To achieve the full functionality of my mode I need to process some text, but I thought that a good idea could be to implement my own set of tags/delimeters (sorry if this is not the right terminology for it) for `org-mode`. I am referring to something like the `#+BEGIN_SRC` and `#+END_SRC` that `org-mode` provides, but with my custom processing. So my question is if there's a way to accomplish this task.

EDIT: Some code to what I would want to get

```
#+MY_CUSTOM_TAG_START
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam

#+MY_CUSTOM_TAG_END
```

Somehow I would like to process the text in between those two tags. Get as a String and use a function (that I already have implemented) to process that text.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom processing"? Please, give a minimal example (assumed Org code and expected behavior).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have added a little code to try to explain what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a source block with a self-defined major mode.
It is easy to define a customized major mode with helper functions like `define-derived-mode`.

Let us name your new major mode `myorg-mode`. Then the name of the function executed on <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> is `org-babel-execute:myorg`.

It is called with two arguments. The first arg is the content of the source block as a string.
The second arg is an association list that maps the keys of the header arguments of the source blocks to their vaules.

The following source code demonstrates the method.

```el
(define-derived-mode myorg-mode org-mode "Org"
  "Add special processing to `myorg` source blocks."
  )

(defun org-babel-execute:myorg (body params)
  "Processing of `myorg' source blocks.
BODY is the text of the source block
and PARAMS is an alist mapping the keys of the header args
to their vaules."
  (let* ((sep (or (cdr (assq :sep params)) "\n")) ;; Example for getting the values of source block header arguments. Here we extract the value for :sep.
     ;; Beginning of the special action for source blocks of this kind:
     ;; We split the body into a list of words and collect only every second word from this list.
     (words (split-string body nil t "[[:space:]]+")))
    (mapconcat ;; Concatenating the collected words to the output string.
     #'identity
     (cl-loop for word in words by #'cddr
          when (string-match "[[:alpha:]]" word)
          collect word)
     sep)))
```

A little usage example:

```org
#+BEGIN_SRC myorg :sep "; " :results raw drawer
,* Some text
Lorem *ipsum* dolor /sit/ amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, ~sed~ diam
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
:results:
text; *ipsum*; /sit/; consectetuer; elit,; diam
:end:
```

Note, if you switch `org-src-fontify-natively` on the content of the source block is rendered like the major mode of the source block would do it. In our case Org formatting is applied.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! The simplest solution was to use your method. I have one more doubt: is it possible to suppress the result output programmatically. I now I can add ```:result none```as a header argument but I want my users to not to worry about it, is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can add `(setq org-babel-default-header-args:myorg '((:results . "none")))` to the code. (That should actually have been a new question. Since it is of separate interest.)